# Instantiate a web user control in a class in app_code

Tags: c#, instantiation, webusercontrol

I am writing a class called Evaluatieform that works with web user controls, their events and eventually adds them to a panel so the web page only needs to instantiate the Evaluatieform class and call a method that returns the panel so it can show it on the website.
Now the problem is that I can't instantiate my user controls I have defined.

First error : The type or namespace name 'DomeinsCriteriums' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So the next thing I try is to drag the user controls needed into the app_code folder. This however, does not work because the compiler does not allow a web user control in that folder.

I read somewhere else to use 
ASP.webusercontrol_ascx usercontrol = new ASP.DomeinsCriteriums_ascx();
However, this does not work aswell.

Can anybody give me a quick solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to load a user control is this.

```
Control ItemX = (Control)Page.LoadControl("/controls/yourusercontrol.ascx");
```

However if you are getting a namespace error.  Simply add the namespace to the top of your page.

```
using DomeinsCriteriums;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, however, both solutions do not work. As he still gives me a namespace error when I type using DomeinsCriteriums;. And for some reason I cannot use Page.LoadControl in a class that is located in app_code?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not read your question properly.  I am not sure why you would want to load a user control inside a class.  I am not sure how you would go about doing that either.